# Merge two data tables with the same rows result in NA

Tags: r, merge

I have two data tables, lets say DT1 and DT2:

```
> head(DT1)
   Tienda  Codigo 
1: Abasto 8519202  
2: Abasto 8610301
3: Abasto 8908001 
4: Abasto 8911602  
5: Abasto 8948801 
6: Abasto 41004301 

> head(DT2)
    Tienda   Codigo SemanaIntro
1: Abasto  43055201          30
2: Abasto  43055202          30
3: Abasto  43055203          30
4: Abasto   8785701          38
5: Abasto  41013401          38
6: Abasto  41129602          39
```

with the same class:

```
> class(DT1$Tienda)
[1] "factor"
> class(DT2$Tienda)
[1] "factor"
> class(DT1$Codigo)
[1] "integer"
> class(DT2$Codigo)
[1] "integer"
```

And I want to do a merge, some of the rows match and some do not

```
> DT3 <- merge(DT1,DT2,by = c("Tienda","Codigo"), all.x = T)
   Tienda Codigo SemanaIntro
1: Abasto      0          NA
2: Abasto      0          NA
3: Abasto 733501          NA
4: Abasto 733501          NA
5: Abasto 733501          NA
6: Abasto 845402          NA
```

Every row of the column SemanaIntro is NA, and they exist in both data tables. There are no duplicated rows in DT2.
DT1 has 35M observations, maybe the problem is related to that.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

edited:
Here is an example.

```
> DT1
   Tienda  Codigo 
1: Abasto       1  
2: Abasto       1
3: Abasto       3 
4: Zurich       3  
5: Zurich       3 
6: Zurich       7 

> DT2
  Tienda   Codigo SemanaIntro
1: Abasto       1          1
2: Abasto       2          1
3: Abasto       3          1
4: Zurich       3          2
5: Zurich       5          3
6: Zurich       6          3

> DT3 
   Tienda  Codigo SemanaIntro
1: Abasto       1           1
2: Abasto       1           1
3: Abasto       3           1
4: Zurich       3           2
5: Zurich       3           2
6: Zurich       7          NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Very stupid thing but difficult to notice.
Every row of DT1$Tienda had a blank space at the end

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I will prefer to use the `rbind` function as this is not really a `merge`

```
DT1$SemanaIntro<-NA
DT3<-rbind(DT1, DT2)
```

Edits:
Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If there are duplicated entries, may be you want to try the `left_join` or `full_join` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
DT3<-full_join(DT1, DT2, by="Codigo")
```

Comment: The rows are not equal that wouldn't work, but thank you for your answer

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't :(. I obtain the same NA column.

Comment: `left_join(DT1, DT2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use rbind.fill (in the plyr package) after filtering which rows to add.

```
DT1$ID <- paste(DT1$Tienda, DT1$Codigo, sep="_")
DT2$ID <- paste(DT2$Tienda, DT2$Codigo, sep="_")

not.in.TD2 <- ! DT1$ID %in% DT2$ID

require("plyr")
DT3 <- rbind.fill(DT1[not.in.TD2,], DT2)
```

In this case, you could avoid using rbind.fill and do:

```
DT1$SemanaIntro <- NA 
rbind(DT1[not.in.TD2,], DT2)
```

Comment: I think that doing that I lose the repeated values of DT1 (that are not repeated in DT2)

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Maybe give a small example of TD1 and TD2 and what you expect for TD3.

Comment: What I wnat to do is what a merge would do, but is not working. I have edited it with an example